# Cannot use jquery or custom plugins without breaking this script

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

I have the script below, which allows tabs in the navigation bar to be drop down in Magento Go. However, when I uploaded jquery to prepare for uploading additional plugins, the custom plugin I uploaded works, but the tab script ceases working once the basic jquery script is uploaded (i.e. jquery-1.10.2.js). When I remove jquery-1.10.2.js, it works again, but I cannot use any other custom script unless I allow jquery-1.10.2.js to be active. I tried all test cases, including changing the loading orders, and that's the conclusion I came to.

Here's the script that works on its own, but stops working once jquery-1.10.2.js or any older version of it is added:

```
Enterprise.Tabs = Class.create();
Object.extend(Enterprise.Tabs.prototype, {
    initialize: function (container) {
        this.container = $(container);
        this.tabs = this.container.select('dt.tab');
        this.activeTab = this.tabs.first();
        this.tabs.first().addClassName('first');
        this.tabs.last().addClassName('last');

        this.container.setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});
        this.onTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bindAsEventListener(this);
        for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
            this.tabs[i].observe('click', this.onTabClick);
        }
        this.select();
    },
    handleTabClick: function (evt) {
        this.activeTab = Event.findElement(evt, 'dt');
        this.select();
    },
    select: function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
            if (this.tabs[i] == this.activeTab) {
                this.tabs[i].addClassName('active');
                this.tabs[i].style.zIndex = this.tabs.length + 2;
                /*this.tabs[i].next('dd').show();*/
                new Effect.Appear (this.tabs[i].next('dd'), { duration:0.5 });
                this.tabs[i].parentNode.style.height=this.tabs[i].next('dd').getHeight() + 15 + 'px';
            } else {
                this.tabs[i].removeClassName('active');
                this.tabs[i].style.zIndex = this.tabs.length + 1 - i;
                this.tabs[i].next('dd').hide();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: did you add `jQuery.noConflict()` after including the jQuery file?

Comment: I have tried noConflict before, but either I did not implement it right or it did not work. You mean put it in its own script tag in the html right after the jquery load, right?

Comment: You can even add it at the end of the jquery file. I usually do it like this because it's easier.

Comment: Which file? In the script above or in the jquery-10 file itself?

Comment: It worked! I put it inside the script I displayed here.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it seems that the issue was fixed by adding `jQuery.noConflict()` at the end of the `jquery.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

There is another catch: You can't put a `type="javascript"` attribute in the next `script` block which solves the conflict:

**BAD**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

**WORKS (CHROME TESTED ONLY)**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

## Edit

Well, I got a little lost since there is no `"javascript"` type, the correct type is `"text/javascript"`.